# Spring MVC 4 + Hibernate + Internacionalization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, locale, hibernate-validator

I'm doing a web project with a system of internationalization for auto-translate the text and messages on my jsp.

I had looked for examples and I'm using a Session object for intercept request (url + **?language=**cod_language)

For example, I have 2 languages supported

Spanish --> cod_language = **es**
American English --> cod_language = **en_US**

I have 2 files .properties for messages in mys JSP and 2 files for error messages for Hibernate, both in src/resources/.

- messages.properties ------------------> WORK
- messages_en_US.properties ------------> WORK
- ValitarionMessages.properties --------> WORK
- ValidationMessages_en_US.properties --> **DOESN'T WORK**

**If I remove the code for country US, then the internationalization for hibernate works. Why? I need that country code to work in hibernate too. Any idea?**

I have configured:

- a bean messageSource; class ResourceBundleMessageSource; with a list of basenames {messages and ValidationMessages}
- a  localeResolver, that works on Session i18n.SessionLocaleResolver
- a mvc:interceptor for all urls /** and catch the param language of the url

Comment: Probably you're asking about `hibernate-validator` and not `hibernate` itself, right? Also, did you try to use `ValidationMessages_en-US.properties` or `ValidationMessages_en.properties`?

Comment: I have dependency hibernate-validator.. but i dont understand that you want to said... Im a newby in spring and hibernate.

when i said that if i removed country code US, the internacionalization Work.. i wanted to say that ValidationMessages_en.properties works.

I test ValidationMessages_en_US.properties but i get a error---> Locale part "en-US" contains invalid characters.

I dont understand why messages with en_US work, but ValidationMessages_en_US dont work, but ValidationMessages_es work.

Comment: Can you post the full error/stacktrace?

Comment: sorry i havent stacktrace, because when hibernate dont fint my custom ValidationMessages, he goes to find default ValidationMessage Hibernate..